# Migrating elastic search from 1.4.3 to 2.4

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used Elastic Search in my project and most of the code has been replaced but i am not any alternative for andQuery(). Docs saying use bool query instead but how to write the code.

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.andQuery(queryBuilders);

Need replacement for this line.

Comment: Please also show the code that creates `queryBuilders`

Comment: BoolQueryBuilder incPlatformEmptyFilter = new BoolQueryBuilder().mustNot(new ExistsQueryBuilder(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_INCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS));

Comment: Please update your question with that code, it will be more legible

Comment: ok i am updating the full code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567010/migrating-elastic-search-from-1-4-3-to-2-4-java-code  help me out