# Migrating elastic search from 1.4.3 to 2.4 java code

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am migrating from elastic search 1.4.3 to 2.4 and 
replaced piece of code referred from elastic search docs and other references need replacement of andFilter?

Code:-

```
  TermQueryBuilder incPlatformFilter=QueryBuilders.termQuery(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_INCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS, platformId);

  //For MissingQuerybuilder
  //MissingFilterBuilder incPlatformEmptyFilter = FilterBuilders.missingFilter(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_INCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS);
  BoolQueryBuilder incPlatformEmptyFilter = new BoolQueryBuilder().mustNot(new ExistsQueryBuilder(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_INCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS));
  //NotFilterBuilder
  //NotFilterBuilder excPlatformFilter = FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_EXCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS, platformId));
  TermQueryBuilder termQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termQuery(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_EXCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS, platformId);
  BoolQueryBuilder excPlatformFilter = new BoolQueryBuilder().mustNot(termQueryBuilder);

  QueryBuilder platformPartialMatched = QueryHelper.andFilterBuilders(excPlatformFilter, incPlatformEmptyFilter);

  public class QueryHelper {
    public static QueryBuilder andFilterBuilders(QueryBuilder... filterBuilders) {

     QueryBuilder filterBuilder = null;

      if (filterBuilders != null && filterBuilders.length > 0) {

  filterBuilder = QueryBuilders.andFilter(filterBuilders);
}
return filterBuilder;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
TermQueryBuilder incPlatformFilter = QueryBuilders.termQuery(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_INCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS, platformId);

//For MissingQuerybuilder
//MissingFilterBuilder incPlatformEmptyFilter = FilterBuilders.missingFilter(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_INCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS);
BoolQueryBuilder incPlatformEmptyFilter = new BoolQueryBuilder().mustNot(new ExistsQueryBuilder(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_INCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS));
//NotFilterBuilder
//NotFilterBuilder excPlatformFilter = FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_EXCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS, platformId));
TermQueryBuilder termQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termQuery(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_EXCLUSIVE_PLATFORMS, platformId);
BoolQueryBuilder excPlatformFilter = new BoolQueryBuilder().mustNot(termQueryBuilder);

// ==> use a bool/filter to replace the "and" query <<==
QueryBuilder platformPartialMatched = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .filter(excPlatformFilter)
    .filter(incPlatformEmptyFilter);
```

Comment: Means the other class QueryHelper having method andFilterBuilders should be removed ?

Comment: That's a custom helper class, it doesn't seem like it is necessary anymore.

Comment: but what will be the code if i want to OR the filters  QueryBuilder platformPartialMatched = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .filter(excPlatformFilter)
    .filter(incPlatformEmptyFilter);  what will be the code?

Comment: Use `.should(...)` instead of `.filter(...)`

Comment: and the above code which i have used for missingQueryBuilder inplace of MissingQueryFilter and     NotQueryBuilder in place of NotQueryFilter are they correct?

Comment: NotFilterBuilder excVariantsFilter = FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.termsFilter(IdxSchemaConstants.FULL_OFFER_ACTION_EXCLUSIVE_VARIANTS, variantIds.toArray()).execution("and"));    what is the alternative for .execution("and") ? and what exactly its usage

Comment: Please create another question, that's not related to this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571400/notquerybuilder-elastic-seacrh-2-4-execution-methods