# NotQueryBuilder elasticsearch 2.4 execution modes

Tags: elasticsearch

what is the alternative for .execution("and") in elastic search 2.4? and what exactly its usage –

```
 NotFilterBuilder excVariantsFilter = FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("products", productIds.toArray()).execution("and"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters and queries have been merged in ES 2.0 and the `execution` mode was only useful in a filter context, so there's no need anymore for that `execution` parameter in `terms` queries.

So if you want an equivalent behavior to this

```
NotFilterBuilder excVariantsFilter = FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("products", productIds.toArray()).execution("and"));
```

you can now write it like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder excVariantsFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (String productId : productIds.toArray()) {
    excVariantsFilter.mustNot(QueryBuilders.termQuery("products", productId));
}
```

It will produce a `bool/must_not` query containing a `term` query for each `productId`, which is equivalent to the previous `not` filter containing a `terms` query with [`and` execution mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_execution_mode)